# "thanks for flagging" popup gets messed up when the comment is automatically deleted

Tags: bug, comments, flags, comment-flags, popups

For some comments, the comment is automatically deleted when you raise a flag. This includes certain keywords and short +1 comments. But when you raise that flag with the new comment flag interface, the "thanks for flagging" shows up in the top right when the comment is deleted:

[image]

[image]

As opposed to what happens when you raise a flag on a comment that doesn't auto-delete:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshots are blurry so I made new ones: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAASU.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz7Vh.png

Comment: @DonaldDuck - they're not blurry, just small. Remove the "m" at the end of the URL (before the file type) to see the full version.

Comment: @​Mithrandir Shouldn't the images link to the images without the "m" when you click on them then, so that you can get a bigger version of them by clicking on them?

Comment: I reproduced this on Brave and Opera for Windows 10.

Comment: This happens on every comment flag not only auto deleted flags. I flagged a comment which went to mod queue and observed this behavior. When I flagged a Thanks comment to reproduced, it's reproduced. That is what happened today.

Comment: @NogShine - yeah, something appears to have changed... I don't like it :(